# Block dock and float options of a TdxBar

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2

I Couldn't find a property or some hack way to block the dock movements of the TdxBar in a TdxBarManager.

I configured the properties in the TdxBar.NotDocking category, this indeed prevent the bar to be docked but it still can be floated around.

im using vcl 2012 1.5

thx in advance.

Comment: So this did not help you? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q340380

Comment: @StefanGlienke thx for your contribution, the answer from mike is exactly what i need in this case but the NotDocking property will the perfect fit for what i have in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a static toolbar, just set the TdxBar BorderStyle to bbsNone (it defaults to bbsSingle).

Comment: thx, i didn't tried to modify this property, the name doesn't sound obvious to me but thats exactly what i was looking for. thx

Comment: It sounds like it is not the solution, but it is, in fact if you change the border the bar remains static not float